# Consuming WCF Service in MVVM architecture in Model class in Windows Phone

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, mvvm

my requirement is to consume the data from WCF service,in a model class and send to view through View-model but it 's not working taking Null Values,Problem is

while calling the method from wcf service **methodnamecompleted** event is not firing.
and not taking the values.
Same code is working in Code behind with normal approach but with MVVM in Model class,showing mentioned issue.
If you have suggestions please help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Patnakar please share the code what you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is help full link 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/hh205277(v=vs.110).aspx